# Split string every 20 characters and then print each section to console

Tags: java, string, split

Okay so, I am trying to do something for a larger project and I need to split a string every 20 characters and then print each section to console with a delay of 1 second between each input
I tried to do:

```
if  (x==true){
  String[] Text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input string").split(null, 20);
  for (int i = 0; i < Text.length; i++) {
    String splitText = (Text[ i ]);
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(splitText);
  }
}
```

But it didn't work (I'm not very experienced with java, sorry.)
Does anyone have any idea of what would work?
(if you could rewrite my code to something that works and explain it that would be fantastic but any help is appreciated).

Comment: The very first statement, `if  (x=true){` doesn't do what you think it does. `if (x == true){` **or** `if (x) {` does. With one `=`, that is assignment - and then evaluation to `true`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry that was just an example condition that I put it in to make it more generalised so that it was easier to understand my example, I didn't actually use that and the if statement was actually happening

Comment: To "split" a string into 20 character chunks, use [`substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-), e.g. `str.substring(0, 20)`, `str.substring(20, 40)`, ..., `str.substring(x, str.length())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method split can not achieve your goal.You can read split method api.
Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression. 
The array returned by this method contains each substring of this string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given expression or is terminated by the end of the string. The substrings in the array are in the order in which they occur in this string. If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string. 
The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded. 
The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results with these parameters: 
Regex Limit Result

```
: 2 { "boo", "and:foo" } 
: 5 { "boo", "and", "foo" } 
: -2 { "boo", "and", "foo" } 
o 5 { "b", "", ":and:f", "", "" } 
o -2 { "b", "", ":and:f", "", "" } 
o 0 { "b", "", ":and:f" }
```

If I do this,I will use code blow:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input string");
        int count = input.length() / 20 + 1;
        for(int  i = 0;i < count;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(input.substring(i * 20, (i + 1) * 20 >= input.length() ? input.length() : (i + 1) * 20));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! It was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This snipet should do the trick:

```
if (x){
    String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input string");
    while (true) {
        if(text.length()>=20){
            String splitText = text.substring(0, 20);
            System.out.println(splitText);
            text = text.substring(20, text.length());

        } else {
            System.out.println(text);
            break;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

REMEMBER that `Thread.sleep(1000)` will stop your WHOLE main thread. You can use something like this concept (threads) to avoid this issue https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Answer (score -1):

basic problem is your system.out.println is outside the for loop, you are going to get at most 1 result, i've redone the basic structure for you below,

also I'm rusty with Java but equals operator I'm pretty sure is == not = (single = is assignment)

also what is splitText, you don't define it or assign its value

```
if  (x==true){
  String[] Text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input string").split(null, 20);
  for (int i = 0; i < Text.length; i++) {
    String memes = (Text[ i ]);
    Thread.sleep(500);
    System.out.println(splitText);
  }
}
```

Comment: Right okay, I tried to make my code look more sensible and I forgot to change "memes" to "splitText", sorry

Comment: `split(null, 20)` causes `NullPointerException`.